# Dynamic number system in Qlik Sense

Tags: dashboard, qliksense

My data consists of large numbers, I have a column say - 'amount', while using it in charts(sum of amount in Y axis) it shows something like 1.4G, I want to show them as if is billion then e.g. - 2.8B, or in millions then 80M or if it's in thousands (14,000) then simply- 14k.

I have used  - `if(sum(amount)/1000000000 > 1, Num(sum(amount)/1000000000, '#,###B'), Num(sum(amount)/1000000, '#,###M'))` but it does not show the M or B at the end of the figure and also How to include thousand in the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Updated to include the `dual()` function.**

This worked for me:

```
=dual(

if(sum(amount) < 1, Num(sum(amount), '#,##0.00'),
if(sum(amount) < 1000, Num(sum(amount), '#,##0'),
if(sum(amount) < 1000000, Num(sum(amount)/1000, '#,##0k'),
if(sum(amount) < 1000000000, Num(sum(amount)/1000000, '#,##0M'),
Num(sum(amount)/1000000000, '#,##0B')
))))

, sum(amount)
)
```

Here are some example outputs using this script to format it:

| =sum(amount) | Formatted |
| --- | --- |
| 2,526,163,764 | 3B |
| 79,342,364 | 79M |
| 5,589,255 | 5M |
| 947,470 | 947k |
| 583 | 583 |
| 0.6434 | 0.64 |

To get more decimals for any of those, like `2.53B` instead of `3B`, you can format them like `'#,##0.00B'` by adding more zeroes at the end.

Also make sure that the **Number Formatting** property is set to `Auto` or `Measure expression`.

Comment: Thansk its working, but another issue occured, I have sorted the chart by measure, now the bar which shows 1.5B it comes at last and another one with 220M it comes first and also the bar height for 220 is higher and bar height for 1.5 B is not visible as it considers the value as 1.5 with respect to Y axis so the bar is not visisble, I hope u understood.

Comment: The Y axis shows labels as 0, 200, 400, 600.. Is there any way to change the labels of Y axis just like the way we did it above for bar labels?

Comment: Just updated to include use of the `dual()` function, which will fix the sorting. It works by allowing you to display a value in a "textual" way (first parameter) but to have it be understood by Qlik in a strictly numerical sense (second parameter). So `dual(2 & 'k', 2000)` will display `2k` but Qlik will interpret it correctly as `2000`.

Comment: And as for the y-axis, I think setting the Number Formatting property to "Auto" or "Measure expression," along with using the `dual()` function, will work.

Comment: Sir now everything gets sorted as I want but now Y axis shows values like - 0, 500M, 1G, 1.5G, 2G, how to get rid of this and replace with millions, billions and thousands just like the bars values we did

Comment: Just thought to give this information - When I change the number formatting to 'Auto', the bar values foe an example - 1.5B changes to 1.5G, and with 'Measure Expression' it shows correct like 1.5B, and in both the cases Y axis remains the same like - 0, 500M, 1.5G, 2G.